# Unable to apply JavaScript minification using Ant and YUI Compressor

Tags: javascript, ant, yui-compressor

I am trying to concatenate and minify my JavaScript files using Ant and YUI Compressor. Below is the code that I wrote in build.xml:

```
<project name="personal-web" default="js_compress"
    basedir="/Users/samsung/Oct4/personal-web">
    <property name="js_source" value="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/js" />
    <property name="target" value="${basedir}/target/yuicompressor" />
    <property name="yui.dir" value="${basedir}/local-dir/yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar"/>
    <mkdir dir="${target}"/>
    <echo>15</echo>
    <!-- Individual file Compression -->
    <target name="default_minify" depends="">
        <echo>Phase 1: Bundling Default JS Files</echo>
        <concat destfile="${target}/default_concat.js" fixlastline="true" force="true"
            eol="unix">
            <filelist dir="${js_source}/"> 
                <file name="defaultjs/multiselect.js" /> 
                <file name="defaultjs/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" /> 
            </filelist>
        </concat>
        <!-- Remove loggers -->
        <echo>Phase 2: Filtering Firebug statements.</echo>
        <copy filtering="true" file="${target}/default_concat.js"
            tofile="${target}/default.js">
            <filterchain>
                <trim />
                <striplinecomments>
                    <comment value="console." />
                </striplinecomments>
            </filterchain>
        </copy>
        <!--  Final compression -->
        <echo>Phase 3: Minifying JavaScript source code.</echo>
        <apply executable="java" dest="${js_source}" parallel="true">
            <fileset dir="${target}">
                <patternset>
                    <include name="default.js"/>
                </patternset>
            </fileset>
            <arg line="-jar"/>
            <arg path="${yui.dir}"/>
            <arg line="--charset UTF-8"/>
            <arg line="-v"/>         
            <srcfile/>
            <arg line="-o"/>
            <mapper type="glob" from="*.js" to="*-min.js"/>
            <targetfile/>
        </apply>
    </target>
    <target name="js_compress" depends="default_minify">
    </target>
</project>
```

The issue is though there is no error, it is not able to create the final compressed JavaScript file. Also I am seeing `no main manifest attribute...` .

Here is a screenshot of the Ant output:

[image: ANT BUILD]

I followed [Sample Ant Build](https://gist.github.com/jasdeepkhalsa/4503658) and [Using Ant to Build a JavaScript Library](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-ant-to-build-a-javascript-library--net-27014) but still no luck.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this problem by downloading yui-compressor-2.4.7 from [Here](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this!!

[YUI Compress master](http://claude.betancourt.us/compress-javascript-and-css-as-part-of-your-build-process/)

Answer (score 0):

The `<apply>` task is intended for running a command multiple times for multiple files.

It appears you're trying to run a Java program a single time for one file. The [`<java>` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) is a better fit for this:

```
<java jar="${yui.dir}" fork="true">
    <arg value="--charset"/>
    <arg value="UTF-8"/>
    <arg value="-v"/>         
    <arg value="${target}/default.js"/>
    <arg value="-o"/>
    <arg value="${js_source}/default-min.js"/>
</java>
```